# Kotlin coroutines: How to flatMapConcat 3 flows, if one of them has not started emitting yet?

Tags: kotlin, flatmap, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I have 3 flows:

```
val flow1 = ... // emits values from the app start
val flow2 = ... // emits values from the app start
val flow3 = someBooleanFlow.flatMapLatest{ if(it) flowOf(42) else emptyFlow() } // emits when user registered
```

I need:

```
val state = flow1.flatMapConcat{ value1 ->
        flow2.flatMapConcat{ value2 -> 
     flow3.flatMapConcat{ value3 -> when{ ... } // so value3 is not received if flow3 is empty, 
// but I need its default value here to perform "when" logics
       }
    }
}
```

The question is how to take a default value in flatMapConcat when one of flows has not emitted?
The issue is also valid for `combine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [onStart](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-start.html) on a `Flow` to emit an initial value:

```kotlin
val flowWithInitialValue = sourceFlow.onStart { emit(initialValue) }
```

You could also use a `StateFlow` for this, and provide your initial value at construction time.

I'm guessing `flow3` represents some kind of user ID for the logged in user.

In this case, I would not use an `emptyFlow()` to represent the non-logged case. You can probably use a nullable user ID or a sealed class as element of your flow, so you can emit `null` or `UserLoginStatus.Anonymous` as a first default value.

Comment: Thank you!!! with `onStart` it works correctly)